# Creating Unique Profile Pages for Users

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've created quite a beefy app. I have a profile page system implemented. Now, I am a pretty big 'noob' when it comes to programming and app engine, so be gentle here, (please). So I know that you can pass parameters in to the url example, /profile/. I'm just not completely sure how to implement that into my code or the thought process behind it.

This would be my database:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    pw_hash = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty(required = True)
```

This is my profile handler:

```
class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.user:
            current_user = str(self.user.name)
            key='ag5kZXZ-c3VpdGVnYW1lcnINCxIHSW1hZ2VkYhglDA '
            imgs  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Imagedb WHERE name =:1", current_user)
            for img in imgs:
                key = img.key() # this is the key
            self.render('profile.html', profile_image = key ,username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, first_name = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country, prov_state = self.user.prov_state, city_town = self.user.city_town)
        else:
            self.redirect('/register')
```

The profile has a display picture system implemented at the moment as well. My goal here is to basically build what you would call a social network. AKA, blog on each profile, and a message system, along with some other systems.

I appreciate any and all help. Even if they are just your thoughts/opinions. I have my site up loadable to a domain, so it would be possible to show you, but I would really like to keep it under wraps until its done :P.

Thanks very much.

EDIT:

This is the solution I saw posted, however I not sure how to go about implementing it.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
  unique_identifier = ndb.StringProperty()
  ...

class ProfilePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, profile_id):
    #profile_id = key name of user
    user = User.get_by_id(profile_id)
    #profile_id = some unique field
    #user = User.query(User.unique_identifier == profile_id).get()
    if user:
       #Get all posts for that user and render....


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/profile/<profile_id>', ProfilePage),])
```

Comment: I find your current set of tags rather general and undescriptive. From them I cannot read what programming language you're using, what framework, or the fact that you are talking about a web-based application. Better tags might attract better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've updated them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to make the profile_id part of the URL and you want that ID passed to your request handler.  This change to your application definition is defining the mapping between 'routes' and RequestHandler objects:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/profile/<profile_id>', ProfilePage),])
```

Typically these mappings are a URL or URL regex with some syntax/convention to identify variables.

In this case `'/profile/<profile_id>'` is a `route template` that uses the name `profile_id` to match whatever is passed in the second path segment.

Any matches are passed as positional arguments to your RequestHandler functions.  This is handled by the framework, you just need to add arguments for each `<name[:regex]>` block in your route.

The reason that the posted solution recommends adding a unique_identifier field to the User model is store the canonical user_id / profile_id.  Say you just use an integer to represent the unique user identity.

Your route template could be changed to only match integers, like `'/profile/<user_id:\d+>/'` and the url for a user would be something like `/profile/1024/`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Alright so i've got all profile buttons in my templates linking to the right pages i.e. (localhost:8080/profile/admin). I passed current_user (my identifier by name of the user) into the profile request handler 'get (self, current_user)' which maps to ('/profile/<current_user[USER_RE]>', Profile). User_re being my reg expression for user creation. I'm getting a 404 error. Something is going on with my mapping...

Comment: You should include your current "app =" line(s) in your question so people can see the exact routes you're using.

Comment: I dont think the other routes apply to my profile page in any way... I pasted the profile route in my msg above.

Comment: Try just making the route constant for now:  ('/profile/admin/') also remember that the trailing slash matters so be sure to specify it when you are entering the URL in your browser.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond. Yes it works if I type it in manually, but I then lose all functionality of my profile image section. I would have to look in to that, but yea it works manually.

Comment: Alright, i've got it working. So my issue now is that my profile image is not rendering even though the code is there in the <img> tag, and I can type in /profile/(anything here) and get a profile page. The img thing I can figure out, but the other stuff is odd.

Comment: Even if you don't get back to me, I just want to say thanks, I got a ton accomplished today :P. I'll def sleep tonight...